# How to automatically install applications/commands when they are run in the Terminal?

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, apt

When you enter a command for an application in ubuntu in the terminal and the application in not installed on the system then you get a message saying `The program 'application name' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install <application name>`

How do you get it to **automatically type the above command for you** or get it to ask you `do you want to install <application name>`

**For example:** say you type **firefox** in the terminal window and firefox is not installed in the system than it will say, `The program 'firefox' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install firefox.`

How do you get it automatically type the command `sudo apt-get install firefox` and **press enter for you.**